# List.All() Change values randomly(?)

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have this code:

```
if (recipe.All(i =>
{
  Item item = inventory.Inventory.FirstOrDefault(x => x != null && x.ID == i.ID);

  if (item != null) 
    Debug.WriteLine(item.Amount +" - " +i.Amount + "->" + i.ID); //Wrong values!

  return (item == null) ? false : (item.Amount >= i.Amount);

}))
```

The *recipe* contains all the items that needed for that specific recipe.

basically the first line (*Item item = inv...*) get a copy of item in the inventory that has the same id as the one in the recipe.

It does work, BUT! the values are changing!

I have in my inventory 3 wood, and when I create 4 sticks (which is 2 wood), the result i get is this:

```
3 - 2->10
1 - 0->10
1 - 1->10
```

x - y ->z

x = amount of the item in my inventory.

y = the amount needed for that recipe (the amount of that item).

z = the id of the item that the recipe is looking for.

What could be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Please pay attention to the preview window as you write the question, there is no reason for your code to be over that far.

Comment: Are you saying that the actual values change or the order of the items in the list?

Comment: Values, i figured that out check my comment on the answer below

Comment: @NaorHadar Should probably delete the question than.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In memory list - no.

If thatgoes to a SQL query, then yes, unless you impose a sort order sort order is not guaranteed. That is one of the first lessons people learn in SQL books.

Comment: Im not using sql. I am going trough a list of Recipe class that i created.

Comment: what could be the problem than?

Comment: Bad code that you do not show? Can not be answered without seeing the underlying implementations.

Comment: The recipes variable is not changed in any part of the game. how come it is changing in this loop?

Comment: Basically recipes is initialize in the constructor and never touched again out of the loop i showed above:recipes = LoadRecipes();

Comment: No idea. Check in debugger whether the content has changed. What type is the list?

Comment: I think I figured it out.. I sent a copy of the recipe to another variable and it most had been as a reference and most had changed the values somewhere else.